# Auditoria nas filas de análise

Tags: debate, auditoria

Hoje me deparei com uma espécie de "pegadinha", a qual o sistema chama de "auditoria", na fila de análise.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Não aconteceu como supostamente deveria acontecer, de eu ter votado sem ler, sem prestar atenção.

Eu entendo que a pergunta em si é de qualidade ruim, mas eu interpretei que a resposta "coloca a questão no eixo". Não acho que deveria ter sido fechada.

Mas o principal aqui não é discutir a questão em si mas o sistema de "auditoria". Não acho que seja uma auditoria eficiente. Para mim soou como um deboche automatizado. rsrsr

O problema que isso causa, por exemplo, eu estava ali doando parte do meu tempo analisando as pendências na fila de análise e de repente aparece isso, como se tivesse de brincadeira. Entende? Dá um desânimo que nem dá mais vontade de voltar a doar o tempo para as análises. Claro que não é algo para se criar um alarde e levar para o lado pessoal, ô puxa, nunca mais volto nesse site. Mas é uma chateação de qualquer forma.

Acho que devem repensar essa automação, se realmente é efetiva da forma como está.

Comment: Eu já passei por isso no SOen e era em uma fila que eu já tinha mais de 1000 análises, estava fazendo apenas por ajudar mesmo. Sei como se sente e também acho que a auditoria deveria ser melhorada de alguma forma, só não sei como.

Comment: Acabei de ver meu nome ali como quem removeu a postagem e fui ver o que era. Nesse caso em específico esse usuário postou a mesma mensagem com um link para o site dele em inúmeras postagens com assuntos relacionados mas em nenhum deles respondia diretamente ao assunto, por isso que eu nem sequer converti em comentário e removi de uma vez.

Comment: Apareceu mais uma. Essa eu discordo do fechamento: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/57755

Comment: Eu concordo que tem muita coisa dúbia na fila de auditoria, que não deveria estar lá. Acho que um grande erro dessa fila é que quem alimenta ela é um tipo de script, pois até onde eu sei não existe nenhuma intervenção humana para decidir qual pergunta entra lá e qual deve sair, ao menos nós mods não temos como fazer isso, só se os CMs tem esse poder e eu não sei. Essa análise em questão então nem dá para saber pq foi selecionada para a auditoria já que nem a decisão dos analisadores da fila foi unânime, [veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/56504).

Answer (score 10):

A auditoria está em testes e o algoritmo ainda está sendo calibrado. No momento, isto não deveria causar efeitos colaterais, como suspensão ou algo do tipo.

É importante dar feedback sobre o que está acontecendo, assim a equipe do SO pode acompanhar e ajustar esses problemas.

Infelizmente, como todo mecanismo automatizado, sempre haverá casos discutíveis.

Por outro lado, particularmente eu acho bom que vez ou outra nós caiamos numa dessas pegadinhas pois isso nos faz prestar mais atenção das próximas vezes. (tipo depois da primeira vez se toma uma multa de radar :P)

Comment: Entendido! Por mim, tudo bem. Pode ter casos polêmicos mas também pode ter casos legítimos. Vamos ver com o tempo como isso pode funcionar. Mas acho que poderia ter outro botão ali, exemplo, tem apenas o botão "entendo" o qual dá uma impressão de "imposição". Poderia ser "concordo" / "discordo". Algo desse tipo.

Comment: @DanielOmine É uma boa ideia essa do botão "Discordo". Talvez seja bom incluir isso como uma sugestão de novo recurso.

Comment: Apesar de ainda estar sendo calibrado eu não tenho a expectativa de muitas mudanças no mecanismo. Isso pode realmente ser desanimador em alguns casos, algo poderia ser mudado para melhorar. Quanto ao botão "discordo" realmente me parece uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que é uma boa altura para voltar à discussão desse tópico. Na minha opinião as auditorias, pelo menos aqui no SOpt, são desmotivadores, as vezes quase que faço tantas auditorias como revisões na fila de analise. Para mim tem sido desmotivador, desde que começaram tenho analisado muito menos, muito por causa disso.

As vezes fico a pensar, será que por sermos bem mais pequenos o algoritmo de auditoria não funciona tão bem? Se for por percentagem (por exemplo) de perguntas em fila percebe-se claramente que sim.

Gostava de saber o que o resto do pessoas acha sobre este assunto e se o @Gabe pudesse dar também esclarecer esses pontos.

Comment: A mim isso também desmotiva. Não pelo fato de sofrer uma ou outra auditoria, mas pelo fato de gastar tempo analisando detalhadamente casos que não são triviais apenas pra descobrir que era um teste (e aí, meus caros, não importa se você passou ou não no "teste", o seu tempo já se foi e a frustração resultante é enorme). Enfim, eu realmente questiono a efetividade desse mecanismo.

Comment: Além disso acho também que são demasiados testes em relação as revisões que faço.

Comment: O problema é o algoritmo ruim.