# Auditoria de análise, o que acontece quando não passo?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Fui pego pela [auditoria na fila de análise](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/auditoria-nas-filas-de-an%C3%A1lise) e acabei falhando, é a segunda vez que acontece comigo, mas realmente eu prestei atenção na pergunta antes de concluir a análise.

O que ocorre caso ocorra mais falhas? Existe um limite de falhas?

Comment: Vc pode ser banido da fila por alguns dias (mas o número exato de falhas pra isso acontecer eu acho que não é divulgado), e o tempo de banimento pode aumentar progressivamente em caso de reincidência: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256231

Comment: Também acho isso...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há critério específico, pelo menos não sei de nada divulgado que indique isto. Só faça seu melhor, a auditoria é usada para evitar exageros e mostrar que seu caminho pode não estar sendo bom. A auditória erra também. O importante é não agir só pra ganhar medalha, faça uma análise com critério e tudo dará certo, normalmente só é bloqueado quem exagera nos erros e fica claro que ela esta votando de qualquer jeito para ganhar medalha.